# From a web browser (most importantly IE), what is the most reliable method for JS to execute local commands?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I can not figure out a security setting in IE that allows for file: URIs to run executables (e.g., window.location.open("file:///C|/Program Files/foo/bar.exe")).

Is there a setting that would make it permissible for certain sites to run things like that, or is there some type of Java applet or ActiveX control that could accomplish the same thing?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example using `WScript.Shell` for **IE-only**: of course, it will trigger the "An ActiveX control on this page..." warning.
(This isn't using a `file:///` URI to launch the app though, of course, but the page is loaded through `file:///`.)

Tested in IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var wsh = null;
                if ( self.ActiveXObject ) {
                    try {
                        wsh = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );
                    } catch ( e ) {}
                    // Check for permission
                    if ( !wsh ) {
                        alert("Sorry, could not get permission");
                        return;
                    }
                    wsh.run("notepad.exe");
                    alert("Notepad should now be open");
                } else {
                    alert("Sorry, this example is IE-only");
                }
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Luckily that's not possible under any circumstances without using exploits or similar hacks.

ActiveX objects or Java applets doing that are usually malware or at least considered to be malware by antivirus heuristics since they usually are exactly this.

Comment: FireFox does have a toggle somewhere to allow this. I am looking for IE's or an alternative method. Thanks for the pontification though.

Comment: @Ben: If FF allows this without *at the very least* a "hey, this is freaking dangerous!  are you sure?" every time someone tries to open a file: url, i'm never using it again.  But something tells me that option you saw doesn't do quite what you think it does.

Comment: Of course there are warnings. I am not trying to circumvent security.

Comment: Modifying arbitrary `about:config` settings can be dangerous. But I somehow doubt it's that easy to let websites **execute** local system commands.